# Sharepoint re-parenting

Tags: sharepoint, reparenting

Is it possible to re-parent a subsite in Sharepoint from 1 site collection to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-parent? Wow! Is that what the rest of us call 'move'? ;)

You can do this with

- [SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100699391033.aspx#2)
- [Saving the site as a template with include content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA101577791033.aspx?pid=CL100605171033)
- [STSADM - The administration tool](http://digitalcross.blogspot.com/2007/10/sharepoint-moving-site-up-down.html)

By the way - if you need more granularity than this (e.g. export a single list) then chek out [Gary Lapointe's STSADM extensions](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/)